# Form validation if @ sign is typed change CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

At the moment I'm configuring a form with validation. Which all goes fine. But I'm trying to get the CSS to change when a user types in the @ sign. At this moment the CSS changes when a user types in more that 4 characters, using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Emailinput').keyup(function() {
        var count = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;
        var imageUrl = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/check.png';
        var imageUrlcls = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/close.png';
        $('#Emailinput').text(count);

        if (count >= 4) {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': '#c1c1c1',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrl + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });            
        } else {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': 'red',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrlcls + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now I would like to change the `count` to an event when the @ sign is typed. Everywhere I looked i found this piece of code:

`if ($('#email').val().indexOf('@') > -1) {`

So I changed the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Emailinput').keyup(function() {
        var count = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;
        var imageUrl = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/check.png';
        var imageUrlcls = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/close.png';
        $('#Emailinput').text(count);

        if ($('#Emailinput').val().indexOf('@') > -1) {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': '#c1c1c1',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrl + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });            
        } else {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': 'red',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrlcls + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any help, to get the CSS to change when the `@` sign is typed? Did I place the code I found in the correct place? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/8w505zmd/ - although I would get rid of this line: `$('#Emailinput').text(count);`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your code is already working, [see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/0bjm6ubd/2/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Emailinput').keyup(function() {
        var count = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;
        var imageUrl = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/check.png';
        var imageUrlcls = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/example/img/close.png';
        $('#Emailinput').text(count);

        if ($('#Emailinput').val().indexOf('@') > -1) {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': 'green',
                'border-width': '5px',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrl + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });            
        } else {
            $('#Emailinput').css({
                'border-color': 'red',
                'background-image':'url( '+ imageUrlcls + ' )',
                'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                'background-position': '98%'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, ok. My bad. The border-color changed to a grey color. So I didn't see the change. Thanks Vincent G.